# Binding an array of dates with PrimeNg calendar is not working

Tags: angular, typescript, primeng

I am using a PrimeNg calendar to select multiple dates, and i bound the component to an array of dates using [(ngModel)]. When i select a date it's automatically pushed to the array but when i deselect a date it's always there.

Here is the calendar template :

```
<p-calendar name="DupDates" [(ngModel)]="DupDates" [dateFormat]="dateFormat" 
           [monthNavigator]="monthNavigator"   
           [locale]="calendarFr" [readonlyInput]="true" [inline]="true" 
           [maxDateCount]="4" [selectionMode]="multiple">
</p-calendar>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So apparently it's a bug in p-calendar, i didn't find any hack to fix it, i just removed the multiple selection and added the dates using `onSelect` event.

Here's the link to the issue : https://github.com/primefaces/primeng/issues/3876

Comment: Instead of `onSelect` event use `(ngModelChange)="onChange($event)"` i have tried it and it works fine. And avoid using javascript events in Angular2+.

Answer (score 1):

Remove square brackets from `selectionMode`.

Replace `[selectionMode]="multiple"` by `selectionMode="multiple"`.